# Parse + iOS: 101 error when saving after a delete operation

Tags: ios, parse-platform

In my iOS app, I have a `PFQueryCollectionViewController` that displays UserPhoto objects. Tapping on a collection view cell opens a photo detail page where the user can add comments to the photo. This workflow works perfectly with no errors until I *delete* a UserPhoto either from the collection view controller (using `removeObjectsAtIndexPaths`) or the detail view controller (using `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock`).

The scope of the issue is broad. When I attempt to perform *any* kind of save operation on any existing object (not just UserPhoto) after performing a delete operation, I get:

`"[Error]: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.11.0)"`

- I've triple checked that I'm attempting to save the correct object, and not the one that was just deleted
- I can log out the objects I'm trying to save and they are well-formed.
- The object I'm attempting to save exists on the Parse dashboard
- The ACL for all objects is Public Read + Write
- The save operations that fail after delete work fine otherwise, so there is nothing wrong with the code that does the saving

The only way to restore `save` functionality after a `delete` operation is completely quit the app.

I'm dying here. Thanks.

**Source Code**

First, a simple function for looping through an array of selected photos from the `collectionView` and calling `removeObjectsAtIndexPaths`. Although `removeObjectsAtIndexPaths` is somewhat of a mystery (limited documentation), I have confirmed that it immediately deletes the objects from Parse.

```swift
func deleteSelectedPhotos() {
var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
    for image in self.selectedImages {
        let index = self.objects.indexOf({ (photo: AnyObject) -> Bool in
            return image == photo as! PFObject
        })
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index!, inSection: 0)
        indexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }
    self.removeObjectsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
}
```

And this is the delete code for the photo detail screen:

```swift
func deleteUserPhoto() {
        currentPhoto.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock { (deleted: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("error deleting photo")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if deleted == true {
                    self.delegate?.photoDetailVcDidDeletePhoto(self.currentPhoto)
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The delegate method near the bottom is called by the `PFQueryCollectionViewController` so it can `loadObjects` and update the UI to reflect the deletion.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the deleted object was really deleted?

Comment: Do you have any cloudCode (beforeDelete, afterDelete) that might affect either the object you're saving?

Comment: @danh, yes, the deleted object is really deleted. I'm checking the parse dashboard immediately after deleting.

Comment: @DavidJirman, I don't have any cloudCode yet.

Comment: Lets have a look at the delete code.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I resolved this. When I was creating new `UserPhoto` objects, I was adding them to an array on the parent object—an `Album`—and saving the `Album` without a completion block. I wasn't actually using the array (instead just querying `UserPhoto` objects with a pointer to the `Album`).

When I removed the code to add the photo to the unused array, I was able to update and create `UserPhoto` objects again. I suspect that the error was referring to the `Album` object which was not finished saving(?).

Leaving the `Album` completely out of the process of updating `UserPhotos` seems to have done it.